# print something exactly after 1 character in standard output in C

Tags: c, input, output

I have a very simple program in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char c;
  int i;

  if( (c = getchar()) == 'a')
    printf("pressed a");

  return 0;
}
```

I would like to print `a` exactly after a user pressed `a` however this is printed only after I press enter. I need to write a much more complicated program where certain keyword a user types in the standard input will invoke certain commands (e.g.: quit/print/read characters) but I don't want to read the whole line in order to execute those commands. I'm learning a university course in C so we can't use any non-standard libraries.

Comment: Use a library like `curses` or `ncurses`. Or if you are not using a `unixoid` then the equivalent for your OS.

Comment: It's not possible using standard C, even if you make `stdin` unbuffered. You have to use operating system dependent functions.

Comment: you can modify terminal behaviour using the stty command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to print a exactly after a user pressed a

You cannot do it without using third party libraries, as the cin file, if it is a terminal, receives data only after the user presses enter.  You may use some branch of `curses`.

Answer (score 1):

getchar() doesn't care about ENTER, it just processes whatever comes through stdin. Line buffering tends to be OS/terminal defined behavior.

Many compilers/platforms support the non-standard getch() that does not require ENTER (bypasses platform buffering).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>  //provides non standard getch() function
using namespace std;

int main()
{  
  cout << "Password ";  
  string name;
  while(true){
      char ch = getch();    

      if(ch=='\r'){  // found Enter key
         cout << endl << "Password is: " << name <<endl; 
         break;
      }

      name+=ch;             
      cout << "*";
     }
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```